# Getting on Eurostar at the wrong station

Tags: trains, france, high-speed-rail, eurostar

I have bought return tickets from London to Lille Europe on Eurostar. The trains on my outward and inbound journeys both stop at Calais Frethun.

Will Eurostar let me get on in Calais on the inbound? What about getting off at Calais on the outbound leg? I suspect leaving the train early is easier than getting on the train 'late'.

Comment: You *obviously* can get off the train earlier than you're supposed, and I'm 95% sure there's no problem boarding the train from a later stop either. (But I have no experience with Eurostar.)

Comment: Good question. Like @Jonik I know you can get off earlier, but assuming they check your ticket at the gate (like they do at London or Paris) I'm not sure what would happen.  I await an answer with interest!

Comment: At some intermediate stations, they do careful checks of departing passengers, to make sure the correct people got off. Mostly this is at Lille and Calais on London bound services (for immigration reasons), but they may randomly do it at other places too...

Comment: Loosely related: [Can I skip my [Amsterdam-Brussels] train leg booked with a KLM flight?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42189/can-i-skip-my-train-leg-booked-with-a-klm-flight)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm afraid not. Eurostar's ticketing rules forbid this. From their [FAQ](http://eurostar-en.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/736):

> Can I board the Eurostar from a different station?
>
> (…)
>
> For journeys from the Continent to the UK, you will only be able to board the train from the station indicated on your ticket.

Starting from the UK, if you have a ticket from London, and your train calls at Ebbsfleet or Ashford International, you can board there instead. Conversely, some tickets nominally Ebbsfleet or Ashford allow boarding at London, but not all of them, check the fine print.

You can leave earlier if you want. This is [official](http://eurostar-en.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/857/related/1) if you have a ticket to London and want to step off at Ebbsfleet or Ashford; on the continent side, since no one checks disembarking passengers, you can in practice.

Answer (score -3):

for an usual speed train(eg: paris marseille), you could take only a part.

BUT as it have a quite carefully control before departure (due partly to immigration), i'm not so sure.