# Can I get off a Eurostar train at an earlier stop?

Tags: trains, france, belgium, high-speed-rail, eurostar

For an upcoming Eurostar journey I'm considering taking, I've noticed a very odd pricing situation. For some reason, the cost of a ticket on the 19:34 Lille & Brussels service is cheaper if I book to Brussels rather than Lille, even though Brussels is further away!

In this case, I know that the Eurostar will stop in Lille (not all do, so you have to check). However, I'm not sure if I would be allowed to get off early? (In this case, I'm interested in booking a ticket to Brussels but getting off in Lille, but I guess it could apply equally to buying a Brussels or Paris ticket and getting of in Calais, or booking a London ticket and getting off in Ashford or Ebbesfleet)

What are the rules on getting off a Eurostar and ending your journey at a station earlier than the one you were booked to go to? (This is somewhat the [inverse of this question on boarding a Eurostar late](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11470/getting-on-eurostar-at-the-wrong-station))

Comment: The earlier question covers both directions.

Comment: There's absolutely no problem in doing so.

Comment: Loosely related: [Can I skip my [Amsterdam-Brussels] train leg booked with a KLM flight?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42189/can-i-skip-my-train-leg-booked-with-a-klm-flight)

Answer (score 6):

As far as I could see, last year, when I was waiting for a TGV at Lille Europe station, an Eurostar train for Brussels called on the same platform I would board my train later. Doors opened, passengers got off then the train departed. In this part of the station like any other in France, the access is open; the usual Eurostar security checks are only for accessing the UK-bound platform. I think this is specific to Lille.

Therefore, you should be able to get off and simply walk out. Double-check your specific train calls at Lille anyway.

Comment: Agreed. In my experience, there is nothing that could be done by them to prevent you from getting off, and also no one checking your tickets at the final destination (i.e., if they were thinking they might try to penalize you).