# Traveling Amsterdam-Brussels with KLM ticket on Thalys - When / where does my ticket get stamped?

Tags: tickets, amsterdam, brussels, klm, thalys

I purchased a ticket to Brussels via Amsterdam on KLM, with the Schiphol to Brussels-Midi portion on the Thalys.  The return portion of my itinerary is on Air France several days later.  This was done in good faith (i.e., not as a fare dodge) since I really do need to go to Brussels.

However, it now turns out that I have a meeting in Amsterdam the day I arrive.

I realise I am required to board the train to Brussels to fulfill the terms of my KLM ticket, and that I will need to get my ticket stamped on the Thalys in order to board my return flight.  What I want to know is where and when this takes place, since I need to return to Amsterdam. Will I need to ride the train all the way to Brussels, or can I get my ticket stamped and then disembark in Rotterdam or Antwerp?

Alternatively, is there any possibility of getting my KLM Thalys ticket issued for a later train, so that I can attend my meeting in Amsterdam before heading to Brussels?

**NOTE**: Some users have marked this question as duplicate.  Be assured that I read other Thalys/KLM questions others carefully prior to posting, but none of them address my key question: Where/when during the Thalys ride does the ticket get stamped?  This is important to anyone in my situation -- i.e., needing to return to Amsterdam after boarding the Thalys, but needing their ticket stamped to ensure their return itinerary is not cancelled.

Comment: Have you inquired with KLM about this ?

Comment: Yes.  They offer no guidance, other than to say that I will need to specifically ask that my ticket be stamped (otherwise, it may just be scanned for validity).  KLM uses the ticket-stamp procedure to ensure that passengers proceed to Brussels as contracted, so they are not inclined to be forthcoming.

Comment: @StanFoster thanks for updating your question. Unfortunately it is already marked duplicate, so please ask it again as a new question and point out why it is not a duplicate (linking to this question and its duplicate ideally) as you did already in your edit. I share your opinion btw!

Comment: As Thalys trains have staff at the doors (at most or all stations) you are likely able to ask by going to the platform but not entering the train. If needed you can go in, get one of the staff stamp your ticket and get out. (In the worst case you may need to go to Rotterdam, as the stops are rather short.) (I did use the train but never as part of a flight.)

Comment: Have you actually read the top answer in http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/42193/30703? It actually describes the process in detail, and answers your question very precisely.

Comment: Despite what you've said in the question, this IS a duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/42193/30703

Answer (score 3):

As far as I remember you just need to pick up the train ticket in the station.

They don't know if you took the train or not, they just know you picked up the ticket on the station and that's all that's needed.

So if you pick up the train ticket you should be safe I think.