# Is it possible to exchange and board Thalys in Antwerp on a KLM flight-train ticket that starts in Brussel Midi?

Tags: air-travel, trains, klm

I hope someone can help me.

**Situation:** I have a KLM flight-train ticket from Brussel Midi to Amsterdam Schiphol (Thalys) to final destination (flight). I have found the information online that I do have to take the train leg and exchange my eticket with a Thalys ticket at the earliest 4 hours before departure.

**Question:** As I live in Antwerp, it would be much more convenient to complete the exchange of the ticket and board in Antwerp Central station rather than Brussel Midi (as the Thalys is very early in the morning). Can anyone share their experience or knows if this is possible?

Comment: Why didn't you book from Antwerp to begin with?

Comment: It was more expensive and to be honest, I had no idea it could complicate things.

Comment: So you wanted to go from A to C, but it was more expensive, so you bought a ticket from B to C because it was cheaper.  And now you want to travel A to C because it is more convenient?  I am sure you can change to departure to A but you will pay the fare difference AND perhaps a change fee.  They are not going to make your life easier.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, if you don't board the initial flight (or rail trip in this case), an airline ticket's reservation for all subsequent travel is cancelled.

If the train is an early-morning train from Brussels, your best bet is probably to take a train to Brussels the night before, and to wake up in Brussels.  Either that, or call your airline to change the booking (or to do so online) and see if the cost to amend the ticket is reasonable.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no tracking of whether the train journey is taken, hence cancellation is unlikely (though probably T&C say they reserve the right to do so).

Comment: @gsnedders If a person is certain about that, then I'd just take my own transport to the Brussels airport, but a person would want to be *very* sure!

Comment: see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42189/can-i-skip-my-train-leg-booked-with-a-klm-flight (it's not letting me @ you, sorry!)

Comment: @gsnedders So seems safe, as long as you actually pick up your train ticket.  Not safe, if you don't get the ticket.  Good link.